# Configure Firebase in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new in Laravel. Please help out on this. How to configure **firebase** in laravel

I am waiting for the response

Comment: You have to describe what have you try. You might see if this [library](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync) helps you.

Comment: I tried this [https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync](https://github.com/mpociot/laravel-firebase-sync)

Could you please help me on this or suggest me any plugin that would be better

Comment: please be more specific in your question: you tried laravel-firebase-sync what problem did you have? give more details please or this is not even a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

To integrate firebase with laravel

simply execute: 
`composer require eelkevdbos/firebase-php dev-master`

By setting your firebase secret as token, you gain superuser access to firebase.

**In your controller**

```
use Firebase\Firebase;

$fb = Firebase::initialize(YOUR_FIREBASE_URL, YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET);

$fb = new Firebase([ 'base_url' => YOUR_FIREBASE_BASE_URL, 'token' => YOUR_FIREBASE_SECRET ]);

//retrieve a node
$nodeGetContent = $fb->get('/node/path');
```